# How to wrap up outputs in Python console within PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

The problem is every output in my Python console was displayed in a single line, as seen in the link, some information have been cut out. How should I change it to let python wrap the outputs?

[Screen shot of `print (reverse_dictionary)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t5RY.png)

**Update:**

Running exactly the same script on another machine within PyCharm, output `print(reverse_dictionary)`. This is the output, [Screen shot of `print (reverse_dictionary)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94fk8.png), wrapped automatically.

Is that a problem because of the interpreters I choose?

Comment: Use[`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html)?

Comment: agree, it is not PyCharm but standard Python console and print output. Use another way of printing if you want to see it different

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `pprint` does work. Just curious, on anther machine, I was running the same code within PyCharm, it doesn't have any wrapping problem, how come? @UnholySheep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not python standard console output. You have to wrap console output. Just go to settings and find "use soft wraps". I don't see them next to the console where I have them.

Comment: The other machine is using Anaconda Python as the interpreter, Anaconda package comes with an interactive mode. I suspect that's the reason it can do print wrapping differently.